# Resources for thesis writing

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, resources

Will be writing my master's thesis in a few months. I have never written a thesis yet though. I was unlucky enough not to be required to have a thesis during my undergrad years. Anybody know some good thesis writing guides?

Comment: I'm sure different suggestions could be offered depending on what your subject, or at least general category, is for your thesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for content or format help, but if it's format-related, I'd strongly recommend the [Online Writing Lab (OWL) at Purdue University](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/).  Actually, now that I double check, I see that it has a fairly comprehensive section on the [entire writing process](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/679/01/).

I like this resource because it's comprehensive, well written, easily searchable, frequently updated, and free.  What more could you want?

Comment: Thanks :D I was referring to the style but the Purdue link has most of the things I want :)